# Ошибка при объединении ячеек в Word. COMException: Запрашиваемый номер семейства не существует

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Делаю выгрузку из datagridview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в документ Word

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с помощью этого кода:

```
string num = null;
int y = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    tbl.Rows.Add(ref missing);//Добавляем в таблицу строку.
    if (num == null)
    {
        wordDocument.Range(tbl.Cell(i + 2, 2).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(i + 2, 2).Range.End).Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value.ToString();
        num = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        if (num == dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value.ToString())
        {
            y++;
            //тут он не может найди запрашиваемый номер семейства
            wordDocument.Range(tbl.Cell(i + 2 - y, 1).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(i + 2, 1).Range.End).Cells.Merge();
            //объединение второй колонки
            wordDocument.Range(tbl.Cell(i + 2 - y, 2).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(i + 2, 2).Range.End).Cells.Merge();
        }
        else
        {//если нет, то просто заполняем данными
            wordDocument.Range(tbl.Cell(i + 2, 1).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(i + 2, 1).Range.End).Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString();
            wordDocument.Range(tbl.Cell(i + 2, 2).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(i + 2, 2).Range.End).Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value.ToString();
            num = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value.ToString();
            y = 0;
        }
    }
    //заполняем остальные колонки данными
    wordDocument.Range(tbl.Cell(i + 2, 3).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(i + 2, 3).Range.End).Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column3"].Value.ToString();
    wordDocument.Range(tbl.Cell(i + 2, 4).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(i + 2, 4).Range.End).Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column4"].Value.ToString();
    wordDocument.Range(tbl.Cell(i + 2, 5).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(i + 2, 5).Range.End).Text = stepennn.ShowSubText(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column5"].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column6"].Value.ToString());
    wordDocument.Range(tbl.Cell(i + 2, 6).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(i + 2, 6).Range.End).Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column6"].Value.ToString();
    wordDocument.Range(tbl.Cell(i + 2, 7).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(i + 2, 7).Range.End).Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column7"].Value.ToString();
}
```

Делаю объединение строк в первой и во второй колонке. Если убрать объединение ячеек в первой колонке, то всё работает как надо. Во второй колонке объединение происходит нормально, а на первой происходит ошибка - Запрашиваемый номер семейства не существует. По логике всё должно работать, но чё то не могу додумать что не так

На третьем цикле происходит ошибка

### Маленький пример

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    var doc =word.Documents.Open( @"C:\\111.docx", ReadOnly: true);
    word.Visible = true; 
    object missing = Type.Missing;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table tbl = word.ActiveDocument.Tables[1];
    tbl.Borders.Enable = 1;

    tbl.Rows.Add(ref missing);//Добавляем в таблицу строку
    tbl.Rows.Add(ref missing);//Добавляем в таблицу строку
    tbl.Rows.Add(ref missing);//Добавляем в таблицу строку
    tbl.Rows.Add(ref missing);//Добавляем в таблицу строку
    tbl.Rows.Add(ref missing);//Добавляем в таблицу строку
    doc.Range(tbl.Cell(2, 2).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(4, 2).Range.End).Cells.Merge();
    doc.Range(tbl.Cell(2, 3).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(3, 3).Range.End).Cells.Merge();
}
```

Заголовок таблицы тот же. В итоге результат тот же, при объединении ячеек в соседней колонке так же пишет — запрашиваемый номер семейства не существует.

Почему так, не пойму

Comment: Давайте локализуем ошибку. В этой строке два обращения по индексу, определите в каком из них ошибка. Добавьте перед этой строкой две: `Console.WriteLine(tbl.Cell(i + 2 - y, 1).Range.Start); Console.WriteLine(tbl.Cell(i + 2, 1).Range.End);` и проверьте в которой из них ошибка. Затем определите чему равны `i` и `y` в этой строке.

Comment: смотрите, если я убираю объединение в первой колонке,т.е. wordDocument.Range(tbl.Cell(i + 2 - y, 1).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(i + 2, 1).Range.End).Cells.Merge(); убираю, то объединение во второй колонке работает wordDocument.Range(tbl.Cell(i + 2 - y, 2).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(i + 2, 2).Range.End).Cells.Merge();. если укажу другие колонки то объединение тоже работает. Не работает конкретно с первой колонкой

Comment: У Вас в этой строке вызывается куча методов. Определите какой из них приводит к ошибке. Тогда сможете сократить [пример до одной строки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). И не придется объяснять людям про вторую колонку.

Comment: делаю так: wordDocument.Range(tbl.Cell(2, 1).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(3, 1).Range.End).Cells.Merge() я указал конкретные ячейки для объединения, ячейка эта есть точно, но суть та же.
Добавил код перед строкой, ошибка та же. тормознула опять же перед строкой с объединением

Comment: Уже лучше :) А которая из этих ячеек выбрасывает ошибку ([2,1] или [3,1])?

Comment: студия ругается на [3,1]. но я уверен что эта ячейка есть.

Comment: Для того чтобы воспроизвести ошибку нужно больше информации о том как строится эта таблица. Сможете [воспроизвести ошибку на маленьком примере](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Для этого нужно будет добавить код создания таблицы в Word, добавления пары строк и объединения по индексам. И наоборот, цикл по DGV можно убрать, мы все равно грид не видим.

Comment: Пример не совсем понятен. Почему Вы пытаетесь объединять ячейки в двух разных колонках? Тем более, что ячейка [3,2] на данный момент уже объединена с другими в предыдущей строчке.

Comment: опечаточка. Первое объединение это ячейки [2.2]-[4.2], второе объединение [2.3]-[3.3]. 
Потому что мне нужно объединять ячейки в нескольких  колонках

Answer (score 1):

Объединяйте ячейки используя [`Cell.Merge`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.cell.merge?view=word-pia):

```
//первая колонка
tbl.Cell(i + 2 - y, 1).Merge(tbl.Cell(i + 2, 1));
//вторая колонка
tbl.Cell(i + 2 - y, 2).Merge(tbl.Cell(i + 2, 2));
```

Вы пытаетесь выделять диапазон не в таблице, а в документе Word и объединять все ячейки в нем. Ошибка возникает при вызове метода `Merge`. Видимо диапазон некорректно отрабатывает.

### Немного о примере

Ошибка происходит при объединении ячеек. Поэтому первый шаг при построении примера выполнить эту операцию отдельно от остальной логики. Для этого создадим документ в котором будет таблица с одной ячейкой и попробуем объединить:

```
var word = new Application();
var doc = word.Documents.Open(@"C:\temp\111.docx");
word.Visible = true;
var tbl = word.ActiveDocument.Tables[1];
tbl.Rows.Add();//Добавляем в таблицу строку.
doc.Range(tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(2, 1).Range.End).Cells.Merge();
```

Этот код приведет к ошибке и мы уже получили легковоспроизводимый пример который можно запустить в консольном приложении. Но его можно улучшить. Для этого можно уточнить какое именно свойство/метод вызывает исключение. Сделать это можно прочитав трассировку стека по ошибке:

```
StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Cells.Merge()
   at WordMergeCells.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Видно, что ошибка происходит в методе `Merge`. Выделим это в примере:

```
var cells = doc.Range(tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(2, 1).Range.End).Cells;
cells.Merge(); //здесь ошибка
```

Это уже будет хороший пример, но при желании и его можно улучшить. Например, в нем мы обращаемся к внешнему документу Word. Его легко создать, но будет еще проще если он будет создаваться в коде:

```
var word = new Application { Visible = true };
var doc = word.Documents.Add();
var tbl = doc.Tables.Add(doc.Range(), 2, 1);
tbl.Borders.Enable = 1;
var cells = doc.Range(tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Start, tbl.Cell(2, 1).Range.End).Cells;
cells.Merge(); //здесь ошибка
```

С таким примером Вы получите ответ гораздо быстрее.